# How to put ajax request inside function and call it when necessary?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/get-result.php',
dataType: 'json',
data: 'pid=' + $(this).attr("id"),
success: function(response) {
$(".reviewee-fname").append(response['fname']);
$(".reviewee-lname").append(response['lname']);
    }     }); };
```

I want to be able to put this inside a function that waits for me to trigger it with a return call. I am not exactly sure how to word it, I am new to javascript and jquery. But basically, I want to trigger this ajax call with various different button clicks and instead of having to put the ajax call inside every button click event, I want to put it in a stand alone function so if I ever update it later I dont have to change it 5 times.
Heres an example of a click event Id like to call the ajax request function with. Thanks!

```
$(function() {
$(".task-listing").click(function() {
//Call Ajax function here.
});
});
```

Comment: why not put the code in the callback?

Comment: `function runAjax() { ..your code ..}` then `$(".class").click(runAjax)` or `$(".class").click(function () { runAjax(); })`

Comment: is there a way to prevent it from running when the page loads?

Comment: If it's in `function functionName() { }` then it won't run until you call it.  I know you say you're new to javascript, but functions are a quite fundamental part of any programming language - you might like to google some beginners guides before asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Callbacks](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced) are well-suited for this scenario. You can encapsulate your ajax call in a callback function.

```
function apiCall() {
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/get-result.php',
dataType: 'json',
data: 'pid=' + $(this).attr("id"),
success: function(response) {
$(".reviewee-fname").append(response['fname']);
$(".reviewee-lname").append(response['lname']);
    }     }); };
}
```

You can now hook `apiCall()`method as a callback to button click.

```
$(function() {
$(".task-listing").click(apiCall);
});
```

By doing this you will able to achieve this.

> I want to put it in a stand alone function so if I ever update it later I dont have to change it 5 times.

**EDIT:**

**Note:**

This is lead to start, you can alter this according to your requirement.

Comment: thank you, if i always want to include other events below the click, can I just add them? or do I need the `.click(function()` as well?

Comment: Wherever you want to use that ajax call, there you can pass `apiCall` as a callback to that event listener. No need to use `.click(function()`

Answer (score 1):

Is this not working for you? ↓↓

```
$(function() {
    $(".task-listing").click(function() {
        let pid = $(this).attr("id"); //get any other value which you want to pass in function, say url
        someFunction(pid);  // pass any other parameters, eg- someFunction(pid, url)
    });
});

function someFunction(pid){  // someFunction(pid, url)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/get-result.php', // url: url
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'pid=' + pid,
        success: function(response) {
            $(".reviewee-fname").append(response['fname']);
            $(".reviewee-lname").append(response['lname']);
        }     
    }); 
}
```